# Add several fields in user-edit.php

Tags: wordpress

I want to insert several fields 'User detail' page NOT when registering, only for the back-end.
I added some codes in user-edit.php and I made a field named 'Company Name' but was NEVER saved!!!
Could you let me know what is wrong or is needed for saving it?

```
<tr class="user-company-name-wrap">
<th><label for="company_name"><?php _e( 'Company Name' ); ?></label></th>
<td><input type="text" name="company_name" id="company_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $profileuser->company_name ); ?>" class="regular-text" /></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

user-edit.php is a core file, and you should never add code to core files. Your code will be erased if any updates to Wordpress happen. I think this stack exchange post should help you add the functionality you want. I would suggest reading through all the answers to find which one would work best, and recommend using Advanced Custom Fields:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/214719/how-do-i-add-a-field-on-the-users-profile-for-example-country-age-etc